# SQL Server, ServicerBroker for asynchronized execution of stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, asynchronous, message-queue

I followed this tutorial:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Using-Service-Broker-for-360c961a

and it is working for me,
However,
I don't understand some thing:
At `PROCEDURE proc_BrokerTargetActivProc` we have infinite loop: `WHILE (1=1)`.   Why ? After all,  during creating queue we bind messages with this procedure:`PROCEDURE_NAME = proc_BrokerTargetActivProc`.

In addition, I am not sure If I correctly understand way of working it:
`ExecuteProcedureAsync` push to queue message with name of procedure to execute.
What now ?  How does it work that `BrokerTargetActivProc` will be called with exactly one message ?

What about parameter  `MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 5` ?

Thank in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three questions here.

---

Q. "Why do we have an infinite loop in the activation procedure?"

A. The idea here is that there is some non-zero cost for starting a procedure. If you have a bunch of messages on the queue, having your already executing procedure handle them is cheaper than executing the procedure for each message.

---

Q. How will the activation procedure be called with only one message?

A. That is an implementation detail of the way that `BrokerTargetActivProc` is written. Specifically, the `RECEIVE TOP(1)` statement. In my environment, I receive multiple messages off of the queue at once (e.g. `RECEIVE TOP(1000)`). That choice (and the implications of that choice) is up to you.

---

Q. What about parameter `MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 5`?

A. In order to fully appreciate this, a reading of [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171601(v=sql.105).aspx) is useful. It outlines when activation occurs on a service broker queue. Having `MAX_QUEUE_READERS` be greater than one says that you're allowing the server to have more than one process getting messages at a time. This would be useful in the case where you have a bunch of messages come in in a short period of time and you want to increase throughput by having multiple executions of your activation procedure active at once to run through those messages.

---

Follow-up questions from the comments:

Q: Who is calling the `BrokerTargetActivProc` procedure?

A: The procedure is called when activation is deemed to be necessary (see the article linked to above). As far as the executing context, you set that when you set the procedure as the activation procedure for the queue. For instance, if I wanted it to execute as `foo_user`, I'd do:

```
alter queue [TASK_QUEUE] with activation (
   procedure_name = `BrokerTargetActivProc`, 
   execute as 'foo_user'
);
```

---

Q: How do you pass parameters to the activation procedure?

A: You don't. The point of the activation procedure is to de-queue messages and process them. So, all of the information should be in the message (which may drive queries etc).

---

Q: What about error handling?

A: You have to be careful here. Anything that causes a `receive` statement to rollback can trigger what is called poison message handling. That said, what I do is I wrap the receive and subsequent processing of a message in a try/catch block in the activation stored procedure and in the catch, I put the message into a table for later investigation. But how you handle errors and what you do with the messages that caused them is up to you!

Comment: 1. Who is calling `BrokerTargetActivProc` ?  2. How to pass additional argument to called procedure? 3. What about errors ? Are there save to queue ?

Comment: The answer has been edited to reflect your subsequent questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "A: You don't. The point of the activation procedure is to de-queue messages and process them. So, all of the information should be in the message (which may drive queries etc)."  I dont understand in exact - does it mean that I cant call method with parameter ? (keep in mind asynchrously execution)

Comment: I did read artice about activation.  I am not sure If I corretly understand it. When `MAX_READER_QUEUE=4` means that `BrokerTargetActivProc` may be runned in four instances (then we have four infinite loop). Moreover,  for me `BrokerTargetActivProc` runs method in synchronous way, yeah ?

Comment: You're right about the MAX_QUEUE_READER setting. But it depends on what you mean about "runs synchronous". Those procedures will be run on your behalf by the server when the queue watcher determines that there's work to be done (i.e. activation occurs). But "synchronous" implies that there's something blocking waiting for that procedure to finish. Which you may *choose* to do. But service broker is inherently asynchronous. That is, messages get put on a queue and they'll get processed. Eventually.

Comment: thanks for your answers.   I ask for some clarification else:  1.  The errors support issue:  How to service errors ? For example, what in case when in our situation I give name such that procedure of this name not exists ?  How to report these errors ? Should it be checked in AsynCaller (I mean procedure which exec procudre given by message) ? How ? By putting message to special queue for error reports ? 2. I dont understand exactly why we need the whole stuff: queue, servies, contract, types,.... I can imagine only queue and type of message. Why services ? Why contracts ?

Comment: We've gone pretty far afield of the original question. I suggest asking another top-level question on "how best to handle errors" (after doing the requisite research/exploration, of course). as to the second question, that's really asking "what were the designers of Service Broker considering?" which, unless one of them happens to be here answering questions, we can only speculate on.

Comment: And don't get me wrong... your enthusiasm is good! I just don't want this discussion to turn into literally everything there is to know about Service Broker.

Comment: Thanks, however I dind't give up : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703381/servicebroker-what-is-sense-of-types-of-message   :)